# Using jQuery Menu Widget as a Pop-Up Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Menu Widget](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) in my Web Forms app.

I threw together a simple demo and it works exactly like the example in the link above.

But I want the menu to be a pop up menu. And when the user clicks somewhere else, the menu should close automatically. Unfortunately, I could find nothing about this at the jQuery UI site.

Can someone point to an examples of use the jQuery Menu Widget as a pop-up menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want a modal window, not an old-style popup.
Why not just give to the menu div a `display: none;` value in the CSS, and then having a script to make it appear? In Jquery it would be as easy as something like this:

```
$("#your_div").fadeIn("slow");
```

where `your_div` is the id of the menu div and "slow" is the speed of the animation. `.fadeOut()` is the function to call to achieve the opposite (your menu disappears).

If you want the menu to disappear when the user clicks somewhere else, you might create a transparent div which is as large as the screen and make sure that the `.fadeout()` function is triggered by clicking on this invisble div.

Comment: Really? I need to create a background div? I'm really amazed that the jQuery-UI menu doesn't support this. I can't be the first person who wanted the menu to pop up.

Comment: create the background div is one of the million ways to do it, you can trigger the fadeOut function in any way you like. By the way, jQuery-UI is a library of UI elements not effects. fadeIn and fadeOut are effects and as such they are included in JQuery, not in Jquery-UI. Frankly if these behaviours were included in the UI library I would find it confusing.

Comment: Yeah, this is an opportunity - get rid of jqueryui and just use jquery + css to create a menu.  Probably there are plenty of "solutions" but it's just adding more layers on a simple problem.

Comment: The solution I suggested does not get rid of jQueryUI. in short: you take the menu from JqueryUI and you take the behaviour from Jquery. One of the typical use cases of JqueryUI is to use it in conjunction with Jquery, I think this is not adding layers but just a straightforward combination of two libraries.

Comment: @mastazi: I'm not looking for effects. I just want a menu that behaves as most menus do: they pop up and close automatically if they lose input focus. My task involves a lot of work besides creating the menu so I was hoping I could find a ready-made one. From the comments made here, it sounds like the jQuery-UI menu widget is not one that meets my needs.

Comment: Johnatan, if you want to do something when the menu loses focus, then the JqueryUI menu supports the `blur` event http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#event-blur

Answer (score 0):

We assembled a jQuery UI button and menu widgets to give us a drop-down menu, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philippm/QEC8N/) for a demo and the full code.

For the HTML you need a button and a nested list, such as:

```
<button>Please choose...</button>

<ul class="accounts">
    <li> <a href="#">Bank</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lloyds</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Barclays</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Cash</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CoffeeScript sets up a menu (hidden initially) and the button to toggle the menu:

```
select_account_button = $('button')
accounts_menu = $('.accounts')

# turn the button into a dropdown that shows/hides the menu
select_account_button.button
  icons:
    secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
.click ->
  accounts_menu.show().position(
    my: "left top"
    at: "left bottom"
    of: this
  )
  $(document).one "click", ->
    accounts_menu.hide()
  false

# set up the menu (hidden initially)
accounts_menu.hide()
.menu
  select: (event, ui) ->
    console.log "selected"
```